# Editing shared boundary of two polygons at same time using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

If there are two square polygons next to each other, sharing a boundary is it then possible to adjust the shared boundary so that the size of both squares change as opposed to making one square bigger and then make the other square smaller?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up [MAP TOPOLOGY](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/creating-a-map-topology.htm), this is NOT the same as Topology that you set up in a GeoDatabase. Search Help file for Map Topology, set it up (very easy) and then the tools that edit shared boundaries enable.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the topology toolbar and tools:

[image]

ESRI has a lot of documentation on this subject:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/editing-shared-geometry.htm